# How to represent a folder with multiple mp3 files in data model in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a flutter app which would play the `.mp3` files stored locally in the device in a certain folder(Root Folder).

Under the root folder, there are separate folder for bunch of `mp3` files belonging to a certain category. Each mp3 inside a subfolder has same - `genre, artist, language etc`.

Let's call these folders - Folder1, Folder2 etc.

The structure is like this -

```
RootFolder - 
          -- Folder1
                  --- f11.mp3
                  --- f12.mp3
          -- Folder2
                  --- f21.mp3
                  --- f22.mp3
             ....
             ....
```

I want to represent these subfolders inside RootFolder(eg: Folder1) in a data model so I can show them as List(using listbuilder and listtile) in a stateless widget.

Here is how I am trying to represent them, it is very basic right now.

```
class Folder {
  String id;
  String title;
  String singer;
  List<String>? tags;
  String coverImageUrl;
  String? lastPlayed;


  Folder({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.singer,
    this.tags,
    required this.coverImageUrl,
    this.lastPlayed
  });
}
```

There are few things that I want -

1. Show all the Folders inside the RootFolder in a seperate stateless widget.
2. Record which mp3 is being played last from each sub-folder(Folder1,Folder2).

First task and second task are interrelated, so I will just ask help for the second.

Issue- How to generate a unique and reproducible `id` in my scenario for the Folder class?

When the user pauses a certain mp3 file, I want to save that particular mp3 file along with the folder id on the db so I can retrieve and start showing it on the player as lastPlayed mp3 from a specific folder. For this, the `id` has to be unique and reproducible while creating object for a folder.

I tried using the folder URI and then feeding it to md5 hash after utf8 encoding, but this wont work if the user renames the subfolder. Is there a better way to do it?

Below is how I am trying to do it now, by calling `getFolderId` when creating object for a folder.

```
String generateFolderId(String folderName) {
  final folderNameBytes = utf8.encode(folderName);
  final folderHash = md5.convert(folderNameBytes);
  return folderHash.toString();
}
```